# Do I need to provide Opencl.dll when deploying OpenCL app?

Tags: opencl

I'm about to deploy an app which has been developed using OpenCL and Nvidia's CUDA toolkit. For app to work correctly on my PC (where I have compiled and tested the app), I need OpenCL.dll. It is located in Windows folder. Do I need to provide a copy of this file when deploying my app to a user which is using a different PC with, possibly, a different graphics card ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - if the GPU supports OpenCL, then `OpenCL.dll` will have been installed along with the GPU driver.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much ! So it comes with the corresponding graphics driver at the target machine.